# Django 'User' object has no attribute 'profile' when I'm trying to log in

Tags: django, model

I had a OneToOne Field relation, but when I added a related name attribute to it, every time I try to log in I get this error:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

Profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
goal = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Try `user_profile`

Comment: Where should  i add it?

Comment: @DánielMozsár Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you have specified that you want to be able to access that model from the User model by using `user_profile`.

The related name attribute allows for you to interact with a a related model through the name that you have set.

In a view you will be able to access it by using: request.user.user_profile

Which will give you the profile of the user that is requesting the view.

Above is one example but in any way that you reference a specific user you will be able to access the profile by adding `.user_profile`  after the user

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still have a question. Im using Djangos built in login system. If i delete the relatwd name attribute my login works, but with it i get the error. Any idea about that?

Comment: @DánielMozsár Edit your post and add in your views.py

Comment: I don't have a view for logins cause django handels that. I had to include the url and that's it. But Django admin login produces the same error aswell

Comment: @DánielMozsár check somewhere in you code. you referenced the user put .profile after it.

Comment: @DánielMozsár in `instance.profile.save()` try changing that to `instance.user_profile.save()`